# how to split & add array values into different 'div' components without using "if" condition?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using HTML5 + javascript for developing a webpage. I have an array with 100 values. And i have a 10 different HTML5 "div" components. I'm adding 1st 10 array values into 1st "div", 2nd 10 array values into 2nd "div" and similarly goes on. I am using HTML DOM to add these array values into particular "div" component.
Here i have used "if...elseif" condition & is working fine.

But i'm asked not to use "if" condition to add array values into different 'div' elements. Is there any other possible methods to do this?

My div components are 'div1','div2'.......'div10'(added in body tag)

```
var myArray = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', ..., 'user100'];

for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
var a = document.createTextNode(myArray[i]);
    if(i<=10)
    {
    var container1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    container1.appendChild(a);
    }
    elseif(i>10 && i<=20)
   {
   var container2 = document.getElementById('div2');
   container2.appendChild(a);
   }
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   else
   {
   var container10 = document.getElementById('div10');
   container10.appendChild(a);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bad solution. The better one is following:

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
//get div1, div2, div3 etc.
var container = document.getElementById('div'+(j+1));
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
//get proper value
var a = document.createTextNode(myArray[i+j*10]);

//insert value into container
container.appendChild(a);
}
}
```

Comment: Of course I've hardcoded number 10 in two places. If you need deal with tables with different lengths (e.g. 200 values), you should replace this values with variables with computed values. For example: var i = 10; var j = myArray.length / i;

Comment: Should `myArray[i*j]` not be `myArray[i + 10*j]`

Comment: element 29 for example won't ever get added like this. myArray[i*j] should be myArray[(i*10) + j]. And the second line should be: var container = document.getElementById('div'+(j + 1)); There is no div0.

Comment: this is better, but it should be myArray[10*i+j], not myArray[i+j*10]. This way the first 10 elements from the array don't end up in the first div.

Comment: Tom, your inner loop use j as an index, my inner loop use i - that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ['user1','user2','user3',...'user100'];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var container = document.getElementById("div" + (i + 1));
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[(i * 10) + j]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var set=myArray.length/10; /** no of sets of 10 **/

 for(i=0;i<set;i++){ //loop through sets

   for(int j=(i*10);j<(i+1)*10;j++){ //loop through each set 0-9, 10-19

     var a  = document.createTextNode(myArray[j]);      
     document.getElementById('div'+(i+1)).appendChild(a);

   }
}
```

Comment: what is `set.length`? isn't `set` already a number which is myArray.length/10? `set` shouldn't have a property called `length`?

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind array values being inserted into each div as one text node, you could do:

```
var div, i;

for (i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
    div = document.getElementById('div' + i);

    div.innerHTML = myArray.splice(0, 10).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 for loops. Do you?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
  document.getElementById('div' + ( i%10 + 1)) //this will give your target div
}
```

P.S: spare me... Typing on mobile...

Comment: this way you only use 1 loop, but you look up the div 100 times instead of 10 times.

Comment: -1 getElementById has a big cost. This is less code but, I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: Yes. I just passed the idea. You can store div in a variable and keep using it. You need to flush it and reassign when i%10 is 0.

Comment: @Snow Blind: I doubt if it would be of that concern; esp after holding the div in a variable until the time we move on to next one

Comment: @Prash Yeah, if you put divs[1..10] in a var than it's OK but instead you asked DOM for the same 10 divs for 10 times each.

Comment: Thanks @SnowBlind: I was commuting earlier. Couldn't type much. Was just passing the idea. Thanks anyhow.